# "Paragraph ended before ..." error in TeX

Tags: macros, tex-core, grouping

While playing around with TeX, I came across a strange error. This is my input file:

```
\def\twice#1{#1#1}
\def\hello{Hello World.\par}

\twice{\hello} % works
\twice{Hello World. } % works
\twice{Hello World.\par} % doesn't work
\end
```

When I compile this with `pdftex`, I get this error:

```
(./hello.tex
Runaway argument?
{Hello World.
! Paragraph ended before \twice was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 \twice{Hello World.\par
                           } % doesn't work
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I remove the line `\twice{Hello World.\par}`, compilation succeeds and I get the expected output.

Why does `\twice{\hello}` work but `\twice{Hello World.\par}` not work?

Will the general technique of changing `\someMacro{someText\par}` to `\def\defText{someText\par} \def\someMacro{\defText}` always work? Is there an alternative that can help me not define a macro for every paragraph that I want to use as a parameter to some macro?

Comment: If you want to define a command which accepts a \par as argument, use \long\def.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid a missing `}` causing your entire document to be swallowed searching for the end of an argument, by default `\par` (or a blank line) is not allowed in a macro argument.
If you want to define a command that allows multiple paragraphs in the argument, use `\long\def` rather than `\def`.