# Find the first character of a string (problem with blank lines)

Tags: macros, spacing

I'm trying to build a macro that gives the first character of a argument

the code

```
\def\FIRST#1{\First#1\TAIL}
\def\First#1#2\TAIL{#1}
```

works almost fine:

```
\FIRST{WORD}
```

produces `W` as expected, but

```
\FIRST{

WORD}
```

gives error `Paragraph ended before \FIRST was complete.`

I have two questions:

1. (the most important) I need my macro work also in case of blank lines
2. (less important) why do I need "\TAIL"? If I remove it, the output of `\FIRST{WORD}` is `WRD`

Comment: First question, [macros - "Paragraph ended before ..." error in TeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562691/paragraph-ended-before-error-in-tex)

Comment: Second question... huh? You know you can just emulate what TeX does by hand to derive the output, right? Maybe read chapter 11.5.1-2 in TeX by topic ((un)delimited argument) if you need something to read other than the TeXbook

Comment: @user202729 nice, I read that chapter, and now I kind of understand why `\TAIL` need not to be defined, but what exactly do my macro?

Comment: As you can tell #1 gets W and #2 gets O (can also verify with tracingmacros)

Comment: If the .tex-file is utf8 while the TeX-engine is 8-bit and uses the package inputenc, then `\First` fails with characters made up from several tokens. Curly braces of category 1/2, spaces  and leading expandable tokens are another issue. expl3 brings along some more reliable routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the linked question, if you want a macro to accept `\par` tokens you should use the prefix `\long`:

```
\long\def\FIRST#1{\First#1\TAIL}
\long\def\First#1#2\TAIL{#1}
```

As for your second question: What happens if we write simply

```
\long\def\FIRST#1{\First#1}
\long\def\First#1#2{#1}
```

and omit `\TAIL`? Let us see what expansion does: when you write

```
\FIRST{WORD}
```

the entire sequence `WORD` is the  argument of the macro `\FIRST`. The expansion of `\FIRST` gives us

```
\First WORD
```

and *the braces are stripped in the process!* The macro `\First` now takes two arguments and discards the second one: in this case the first argument (kept) is `W`, and the second one (discarded) is `O`. The expansion of `\First WO` is thus `W`, and the other two tokens `RD` are still there, giving you `WRD`.

On the other hand, with the definition

```
\long\def\First#1#2\TAIL{#1}
```

the second argument `#2` is a *delimited* argument. `\First` considers the first token (or braced list) as first parameter, and everything up to `\TAIL` as the second one.